# Prove that $243^{2020} \equiv 1 \pmod 5$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I was supposed to use that  $a^4 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$, but that's not helping me, specifically, I don't know how to prove that $243^{505}$ is not as $5k, k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Apply the first corollary in the linked dupe with $\,e = 4.\ \ $

Answer (score -1):

$$243^{2020}=(243^4)^{505}\equiv (3^4)^{505}\equiv 1^{505}\equiv 1\pmod 5 $$

Comment: Please strive not to add yet more diupe answers to FAQs.